# How to show that a ternary code of block length $8$ that can correct all single errors cannot contain more than $385$ words

Tags: field-theory

Let $C$ be a ternary (not necessarily linear) code of block length $8$ that can correct all single errors. Show that $C$ cannot contain more than $385$ code words.

How do you solve this and how does it differ from a binary version? 
I can answer the same question say for block length $8$ in a binary code. Show C has at most $28$ code words:

DERIVATION

C can correct all single errors therefore d(E)>=3. The vector space of dimension 8 over Z_2 has (2^8) elements.

If U an element of Z_2 is a code word of E another element is v an element of Z_2 is a code word iff d(u,v) >= d(E)

Let Su:= { W e Z_2 | d(u,v) <= [d(E)/2]}

Where u = code word. Su only contains one code word = u.

The number of code words in E (2^8)/|Su| reaches a max when |Su| is min. This happens when d(E) =min therefore d(E) =3

Count the number of w in Z_2 such that d(u,w) <=(3/2)

d(u,w)=0, w=u

d(u,w)=1

Therefore there are 8 options for word w such that d(u,w) =1 and Su has 9 elements.

Hence,

$$\dfrac{2^8}{9} = 28$$

How do I solve the analogous problem for a ternary code?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Did you mean to write $$\lfloor \frac{2^8}{9} \rfloor$$  If so, type \lfloor \frac{2^8}{9} \rfloor between dollar signs for an inline equation or between double dollar signs for a displayed equation.

Comment: Can you really answer for the binary version, or do you just have the answer? Please write out the derivation that yielded the result for binary codes.

Comment: @bukwyrm I've now shown my proof

Comment: Imagine a three-dimensional (= Block length) grid. Every grid-dimension has only three positions, say 0,1,2 (= ternary). There are 27 blocks in that grid (= three(=ternary) to the power of three(=block length)). Every block represents one possible word. To be 1-error-correctable, a CODEword must be a word that has so much distance from the other CODEwords, that any single error (= shifting the block by one or more positions on ONE dimension) will a) not shift it into another CODEword , and b) not shift it into a position where it could be shifted into another CODEword by ONE other dimension

Comment: So for instance if you have 000 as codeword, 111 and 222 is not reachable by 2 1-dimensional shifts. Therefore with the three codewords 000,111,222, you can be sure that whatever ONE 1-dimensional shift you do on 000 (001, 100, 010) can not have been effected by ONE 1-dimensional shift (=1-error) of another codeword) So now you can reset 001 010 and 100 to 000, because you assume that only one error happened. If 2 errors happened, you would still see it, but you may assume that it was 1 errror from another codeword, thereby mis-correcting it. Now solve how many  codewords can maximally exist.

Comment: the above is only valid for block lenght 3! It was just an example to make the problem more visually imaginable.

Comment: (BlockSize*(AlphabetSize-1)) + 1 = (GridDimensions * (Gridlength-1)) + 1 = Number of "forbidden" words per codeword (FWPC), because that is the number of words that can be reached with one shift. In my above example that's 7.  If you divide the possible words by the FWPC, you get the max number of codewords for error DETECTION. In the above example that's 28/7 = 4.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- How many different ternary strings with $8$ characters are there?
- Given a particular string, how many strings are either exactly that string or differ from it in one place?